# Python 2.x subprocess.PIPE from different threads get mixed with parallel_map

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, pipe, subprocess

I am using subprocess.Popen and subprocess.PIPE in order to load a perl script and let it regularly serve requests from python code. I have noticed that when requests are served with parallel_map over the same Popen subprocess, perl output from different requests gets mixed.

```
class CommandlinePreprocessor:

    def __init__(self, path, lang, params = {}, command_template = ""):
        self.lang = lang
        params["lang"] = lang
        params["path"] = path
        self.command = command_template.format(**params)
        command_items = self.command.split(' ')
        self.output = []
        self.running = True

        self.process = subprocess.Popen(command_items, 
                                        shell=False, 
                                        bufsize=1, 
                                        stdin=subprocess.PIPE, 
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                        )


    def process_string(self, string):

        string = string.encode('utf-8')
        #write to the stdin pipe followed by some space bytes in order to flush
        self.process.stdin.write('{0}{1}\n'.format(string, ' '*10240))
        self.process.stdin.flush()   
        self.process.stdout.flush()

        output = self.process.stdout.readline().strip()

        #some preprocessors occasionally return an empty string. In that case read once more
        if output == "" and len(string) > 1:
            output = self.process.stdout.readline().strip()

        return output

class Truecaser(CommandlinePreprocessor):
    def __init__(self, lang, model):
        directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        path = os.path.join(directory, 'truecase.perl')
        command_template = "perl {path} -model {model}"
        super(Truecaser, self).__init__(path, lang, {"model": model}, command_template)


class CompoundSplitter(CommandlinePreprocessor):
    def __init__(self, lang, model):
        directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
        path = os.path.join(directory, 'compound-splitter.perl')
        command_template = "perl {path} -model {model}"
        super(CompoundSplitter, self).__init__(path, lang, {"model": model}, command_template)   


def process_task(src_lines):
    def _translator(line):
        return translate(line)
    translated = parallel_map(_translator, src_lines)
    return translated

def _translate(line):
    preprocessors = [Truecaser, CompoundSplitter] #these two extend the CommandlinePreprocessor
    for preprocessor in preprocessors:
        logger.debug("Preprocessed source before {}: {}".format(preprocessor.__class__.__name__, src))
        src = preprocessor.process_string(src)
        logger.warning("Preprocessed source after {}: {}".format(preprocessor.__class__.__name__, src))
    return src
```

Here comes my input:

```
lines = ["Das ist eine Probe . ", "Sie ist die letzte . ", "Nach mehrere Experimenten , kann ich noch nicht sagen , wie lange es dauert .", "Das Termin ist noch nicht fest , allerdings."]
process_task(lines)
```

and this is the logger output. The parallel map launches 4 threads which altogether try to communicate with the Truecaser script. This schript is only supposed to change the capitalization of the words. As you can see, the words get messed up between the different calls.

```
Preprocessed source before Truecaser: Das ist eine Probe .
Preprocessed source before Truecaser: Sie ist die letzte .
Preprocessed source before Truecaser: Nach mehrere Experimenten , kann ich noch nicht sagen , wie lange es dauert .
Preprocessed source before Truecaser: Das Termin ist noch nicht fest , allerdings .
Preprocessed source after Truecaser: eine
Preprocessed source before CompoundSplitter: eine
Preprocessed source after CompoundSplitter: eine
Preprocessed source after Truecaser: das . die
Preprocessed source before CompoundSplitter: das . die
Preprocessed source after CompoundSplitter: das . die
Preprocessed source after Truecaser: sie  .nach mehrere ,kann  noch  ,  lange  dauert.
Preprocessed source before CompoundSplitter: sie  .nach mehrere ,kann  noch  ,  lange  dauert.
Preprocessed source after Truecaser: istProbeist letzte  Experimenten ichnicht sagenwiees  das Termin ist noch nicht fest , allerdings .
Preprocessed source after CompoundSplitter: sie .nach mehrere ,kann noch , lange dauert.
Preprocessed source before CompoundSplitter: istProbeist letzte  Experimenten ichnicht sagenwiees  das Termin ist noch nicht fest , allerdings .
Preprocessed source after CompoundSplitter: istProbeist letzte Experimenten ichnicht sagenwiees das Termin ist noch nicht fest , allerdings .
```

Comment: could you [create a *minimal* code example that shows the issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Hm. I would have to include and minimize somehow a perl script then?

Comment: you could start by removing irrelevant parts from your Python code.